# How to use conditionals to assign a @track variable in JS when building a custom LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have built a custom list view that lists custom objects. The list view component allows filtering based on a field of the custom object. This all works smoothly, but I want to add a feature where the default filter view is based on the profile the user is viewing from. Currently it is default to "All".

Comment: What is `ALL`? A variable or string?

Comment: A constant variable. In my file I have `const ALL = 'All';`.

Comment: In that case you can assign the value in `connectedCallback()` like `this.currentFilter = this.ALL;` or simply use it like `@track currentFilter = 'All';` in the declaration.

Comment: What is connectedCallback? How can this track my `userId` variable and assign the correct filter option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably modify the code a bit like -

```
@track currentFilter;
@wire(getUserId, {})
getUserIdData({ error, data }) {
    if(data) {
        if (data === '00e1F000000mZ8y') { // if it is DF profile
            this.currentFilter = this.DF;
        } else if (data === '00e1F000000mZ9D') { // if it is RAC profile
            this.currentFilter = this.RAC
        } else {
            this.currentFilter = this.ALL;
        }
    } else if (error) {
      //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, except I had my `getUserId` method return a String instead (since I don't know what data type `DF`, `RAC`, and `ALL` would be for when specifying what kind of data type to return. I did the comparisons in your if statements in my method itself, However it looks like it still defaults to `ALL` :(

Comment: Please modify your question and add the Apex logic. It defaults to ALL probably because no other conditions are matching. Also if you could shed more clarity on what you are looking for that would be helpful.

Comment: I modified my question with the asked information!

Comment: I see what's wrong. `UserInfo.getProfileId()` would return 18 char ID and you are comparing with 15 char. So the checks are failing and it is going to `else` block.

Comment: Wait, are profile ID's 18 chars? The profile ID for the profiles I want are 15 chars - and I was able to check this with an SOQL query..

Comment: Wait, never mind!!!! Thank you so much, I found the 18 char ID. It works now, thank you again

Comment: 15 digit case-sensitive version is referenced in the UI and also visible in browser
18 digit case-insensitive version which is referenced through the API